# Permutations of English Alphabet of a given length

Tags: c++, string, permutation, alphabet

So I have this code. Not sure if it works because the runtime for the program is still continuing.

```
void permute(std::vector<std::string>& wordsVector, std::string prefix, int     length, std::string alphabet) {
if (length == 0) {
    //end the recursion
    wordsVector.push_back(prefix);
}
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); ++i) {
        permute(wordsVector, prefix + alphabet.at(i), length - 1, alphabet);
    }
}}
```

where I'm trying to get all combinations of characters in the English alphabet of a given length. I'm not sure if the approach is correct at the moment.

Alphabet consists of A-Z in a string of length 26. WordsVectors holds all the different combinations of words. prefix is meant to pass through recursively until a word is made and length is self explanatory.

Example, if I give the length of 7 to the function, I expect a size of `26 x 25 x 24 x 23 x 22 x 21 x 20 = 3315312000` if I'm correct, following the formula for permutations. 
I don't think programs are meant to run this long so either I'm hitting an infinite loop or something is wrong with my approach. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't use recursions on this.  With the number of function calls involved I am surprised you haven't hit a stack overflow.

Comment: the program will take long as the complexity is given by selecting n(n<=26) things from 26 and then permuting it. It will increase very fast for n and thus the complexity is high. Its not an infinite loop will just take incredibly long

Comment: Do you have enough memory to store the words?

Comment: 3315312000 * 7 plus allocation overhead is around 128GB of memory. Do you have 128GB of memory? If not, you're probably swapping very heavily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the stack would overflow but concentrating on your question even if you write an iterative program it will take a long time ( not an infinite loop just very long )

```
[26L, 650L, 15600L, 358800L, 7893600L, 165765600L, 3315312000L, 62990928000L, 1133836704000L, 19275223968000L, 308403583488000L, 4626053752320000L, 64764752532480000L, 841941782922240000L, 10103301395066880000L, 111136315345735680000L, 1111363153457356800000L, 10002268381116211200000L, 80018147048929689600000L, 560127029342507827200000L, 3360762176055046963200000L, 16803810880275234816000000L, 67215243521100939264000000L, 201645730563302817792000000L, 403291461126605635584000000L, 403291461126605635584000000L]
```

The above list is the number of possibilities for `1<=n<=26`. You can see as `n` increases number of possibilities increases tremendously. Say you have 1GHz processor that does 10^9 operations per second. Say consider number of possibilities for `n=26` its 403291461126605635584000000L. Its evident that if you sit down to list all possibilities its so so long ( so so many years ) that
you will feel it has hit an infinite loop. Finally I have not looked that closely into your code , but in nutshell even if you write it correctly,iteratively and don't store (again can't have this much memory) and just print all possibilities its going to take long time for larger values of `n`.

**EDIT**

As jaromax and others said if you just want to write it for smaller values of `n`,
say less than 10-12 you can write an iterative program to list/print them. It will run quite fast for small values. But if you also want to store them them then `n` will have to be say less than 5 say. (Really depends on how much RAM is available or you could find some permutations write them to disk, then depends on how much disk memory you can spare, again refer the number of possibilities list I posted above. It gives a rough idea of both time and space complexity).

Comment: Alright I see what you mean., what if instead of storing I use these to look up words in a dictionary stored by a binary search tree?

Comment: then memory complexity would be fine but time complexity would still be bad as I said even printing all possibilities one by one takes time. So any computation on all possibilities one by one is bound to take long time.

Answer (score 1):

I think there could be quite a problem that you do this on stack. A large part of the calculation you do recursively and this means every time allocated space for function.

Try to reformulate it linearly. I think I had such a problem before.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thank you. You are right that I need a reputation to comment. However, I still think, that I have **given an answer**.... Supposing @Kthieu did his calculus correct and he has  3315312000 combinations, (7 letters I get 3e+8 combinations), you need 2GB to store and I just tested plain C and I can do 20milions  operations like this `r=r*n/(n+1)+r/n;` per second.  My resume - no problem if do it in heap.

Answer (score 1):

Your question implies you think there are 26x25x24x ... permutations

Your code doesn't have anything I can see to avoid "AAAAAAA" being a permutation, in which case there are 26x26x26x ...

So in addition to being a very complicated way of counting in base 26, I think it's also giving bad answers?

Comment: I see it now. I always start from the first letter of the alphabet huh. but combinations like ABAAAAA also exist right?

Comment: If you were doing numbers you'd get 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004 .... that you are using letters instead isn't really important, you are basically counting in base 26 and storing every value as a string .... I was trying to say that it seems like a strange thing to do, and a strange way to do it?